# How to create modbus master/server tcp in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, protocols, modbus, modbus-tcp

I want to create desktop app to communicate with PLC using modbus. I found [modbus](https://pub.dev/packages/modbus) package, but I can not implement modbus server. There is only client implementation. I've read [modbus](https://pub.dev/packages/modbus) source code and found that modbus client was created using `Socket` from `dart:io`. Can we create modbus server using `ServerSocket`?. I've tried to create tcp server using `ServerSocket` and modbus client then connect it. Modbus client can connect to tcp server and tcp server will receive `Uint8List` data if modbus client do `writeSingleRegister` or `readHoldingRegisters`.

Server socket will receive this data if modbus client do write single register with address 4 and value 5

```
[0,1,0,0,0,6,10,6,0,4,0,5]
```

- `1` is sequence
- The second `6` => always 6 for `write single register`
- `4` is address
- `5` is value

Server socket wil receive this data if modbus client do read single register with address 4 and amount 5

```
[0,1,0,0,0,6,10,3,0,4,0,5]
```

- `1` is sequence
- `3` => always 3 for `read single register`
- `4` is address
- `5` is amount

**Create server**

```
void createServer(){
    ServerSocket.bind("127.0.0.1", 4000)
        .then((server) {
      server.listen((socket) {
        socket.listen((event) {
          print(event);
          // how to send data result to client?
          // socket.write() and socket.add() give errors
          socket.write(Uint16List.view(event.buffer,0,1));
          // error => Unhandled Exception: RangeError (byteOffset): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4
        });
      });
    });
}
```

```
Future<void>read(modbus.ModbusClient client,int address, int amount)async{
    Uint16List data = await client.readHoldingRegisters(address, amount);
    print(data);
  }
```

**Problem**

How to send data to modbus client if client do `readHoldingRegisters`
using `ServerSocket`?